Running tsc on an eslint.config.js raises error
I am running tsc --skipLibCheck with the files below:
eslint.config.js:
// @ts-check
import jslint from "@eslint/js"

export default []

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "files": ["eslint.config.js"]
}


I get the following error:
eslint.config - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@eslint/js'. './node_modules/@eslint/js/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How to do to ignore type check on imports?

If you want to just ignore type checking on an untyped import (judged by TS to be implicitly any), you can do like so:
// @ts-expect-error - @eslint/js is not typed
import jslint from "@eslint/js"

export default []

This TS decorator will remove the error while there is an error, or raise a warning/error when there is no error. This will allow you to know when to remove the decorator.
Less safely, you can use:
// @ts-ignore - @eslint/js is not typed
import jslint from "@eslint/js"

export default []

Which will always ignore type checking.
Since ESLint 9 and the flat config are quite new, it is probable the types have not yet been added to the core library. Down the lines you may encounter more issues with typing and the likes; I personally still use 8.57.0 which has better compatibility with many configs nowadays.
Good luck with your TypeScript project :)

If you prefer skipping typechecking, you can follow the other answer.
If you would like to correct the type checking, install the @types/eslint__js package, which contains the type information of @eslint/js:
npm i --save-dev @types/eslint__js

